# Google Apps Script Get Share Link of File Uploaded to OneDrive

Tags: google-apps-script, onedrive

I'm using the OnedriveApp library created by @Tanaike to copy files from google drive to OneDrive as in the below code block. The result includes an id and file name, and I'm curious if it is possible to get share link to the file as well or create one from the aforementioned. Really appreciate any help, I'm pretty familiar with apps script but new to Microsoft and Microsoft Graph.

```
function copyFile(fileid){
  var prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var odapp = OnedriveApp.init(prop);
  var res = odapp.uploadFile(fileid,"/Reports/");
  Logger.log(res);
}
```

I've looked into doing this with Power automate, but I'm unsure how I would integrate the two, I have very little familiarity with Power automate

Comment: I think I answered the question and apologies for the oversight, it looks like url can be easily constructed from file name